# NOT IN a specific table using MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have two tables:

1. One holds all posts from my members and
2. another holds ids of the post, and the users id to hide the post on their page

How can I select all posts except for those that are not in the hide table?

Pseudo statement example...

> "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE NOT IN (other table)"

This is what I have so far

```
SELECT * FROM `acmPosting` LEFT JOIN `hidePosts` ON acmPosting.id = hidePosts.postID WHERE `sender`='$userID' OR `recip`='$userID' OR `sender` IN ($friendsArray) OR `recip` IN ($teamsArray) AND hp.id IS NULL ORDER BY `timeSent` DESC LIMIT 10
```

Comment: all posts except those not in the hide table ... so basically, all posts in the hide table?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `SELECT * FROM posts WHERE ID NOT IN (other table)"`  You forgot to write `ID`

Comment: can you share your table structure ?

Comment: @MahmoudGamal Why did you delete your answer? I was just nitpicking at the one sentence - it was still a good answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is known as an anti-join and should be equivalent using `NOT IN` (though with a different query plan):

```
SELECT *
FROM posts p
LEFT JOIN hiddenPosts hp on hp.id = p.id
WHERE hp.id IS NULL
;
```

See this article for more information: [NOT IN vs. NOT EXISTS vs. LEFT JOIN / IS NULL](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/)

Comment: This seems like an awesome solution for me, but I can't seem to get it working. This is what I have SELECT * FROM `acmPosting` LEFT JOIN `hidePosts` ON acmPosting.id = hidePosts.postID WHERE `sender`='$userID' OR `recip`='$userID' OR `sender` IN ($friendsArray) OR `recip` IN ($teamsArray) AND hp.id IS NULL ORDER BY `timeSent` DESC LIMIT 10

Comment: never mind i was using a shortcut in the IS NULL field. Got it working now

Answer (score 5):

Assume the second table is postHides, and both of the tables have a postId column:

```
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE postId NOT IN (SELECT postId FROM postHides)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT post.* FROM post LEFT JOIN foo ON post.id = foo.post_id WHERE foo.post_id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 2):

Suppose the other table is named `hide_list` and the *foreign key* of `posts.id` in it is `fk_post_id`.
Then the select statement will be:

```
SELECT posts.* from posts,hide_list WHERE NOT posts.id=hide_list.fk_post_id;
```

A more optimized solution will be:

```
SELECT posts.* from posts,(SELECT fk_post_id from hide_list) hide_list WHERE NOT posts.id=hide_list.fk_post_id;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
"SELECT * FROM posts WHERE post_id NOT IN (select post_id from other_table)"
```